# "The Struts dispatcher cannot be found" error while deploying application on WebLogic 12.1.3

Tags: java, tomcat, struts2, web.xml, weblogic12c

I have the following error while trying to run my application on WebLogic 12.1.3.

> The Struts dispatcher cannot be found.  This is usually caused by using Struts tags without the associated filter. Struts tags are only usable when the request has passed through its servlet filter, which initializes the Struts dispatcher needed for this tag.

This is my `web.xml` file :

```xml
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:web="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

<display-name>SybUI</display-name>
<!-- location of log4j config file -->
<!-- <context-param>
    <param-name>log4jConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/classes/log4j2.xml</param-value>
</context-param> -->

<filter> 
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter
    </filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
 <listener>
    <listener-class>
        org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener
    </listener-class>
</listener>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
    </listener-class>
</listener>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener
    </listener-class>
</listener>
<!-- <filter>
    <filter-name>SessionFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.syb.core.filter.SessionFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>avoid-urls</param-name>
        <param-value>/timeOut,/pages/timeOut.jsp,/test,/pages/test.jsp,/testMsg.action,/pages/invalidToken.jsp,/login.jsp,/logoutUser,/loginUser.action,
            /common/postloginheader.html,/js/jquery.mobile.custom.min.js,/images/plus_cyn_40.png,/js/custom.js,/css/bootstrap.min.css,/css/aos-style.css,
            /css/style.css,/js/bootstrap.min.js,/js/modernizr.min.js,/css/custom.css,/js/jquery.validate.min.js,/js/respond.min.js,/js/session1.js,/js/aos-custom.js,
            /images/wres009899.png,/images/fdic.png,/images/header_1024.jpg,/images/blue-arrow.png
        </param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>SessionFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>-->
    <!--<session-config>
    <session-timeout>10</session-timeout>
</session-config> -->

<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>/jsp/ao/ApplicationStartUp.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>

<error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/jsp/common/error/Error-PageNotFound.jsp</location>
</error-page>

<error-page>
    <exception-type>java.lang.Throwable</exception-type>
    <location>/jsp/common/error/Error-PageNotFound.jsp</location>
</error-page>
```

Comment: Have you read the error message? Which part you didn't understand?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Struts tags inside JSP page that has listed in the `welcome-file-list` it should be removed.

### [`welcome-file-list` in `web.xml`](http://www.javatpoint.com/welcome-file-list):

> The `welcome-file-list` element of `web-app`, is used to define a list of welcome files. Its sub element is `welcome-file` that is used to define the welcome file.
>
> A welcome file is the file that is invoked *automatically* by the server, if you don't specify any file name.

And hence without associated filter. The associated filter is defined `struts2` mapped to `/*`. It means it should serve all requests, unless the welcome file is served by the web server.

Normally, you should not directly access JSP pages without prior action execution, that returns a `dispatcher`' type result. In this result you can specify the location of the JSP file you want to get the access.

The `welcome-file-list` files are handled by the web container if you navigate to the folder of your web content hierarchy, such as if you aren't using the `.action` extension in the URL, and there's a `welcome-file` inside it, and there's no action mapped to that URL. In this case you cannot use struts tags inside the `welcome-file` because you are trying to run it without associated filter, or the struts2 filter is already handled another request.

Comment: Thanks a lot! However, the same mechanism works on Tomcat! How is that?

Comment: The Tomcat also a servlet container. All web servers that implement servlet specs has this feature, and all of them use `web.xml`.

Comment: @RomanC  I noticed that mine `welcome-file-list` working fine on glassfish server 4.1.*, under  `welcome-file-list` element   i define jsp file which has struts2 tag . But as you said it not supposed to work, isn't it ?

Answer (score 0):

You are using Struts tags inside a JSP, probably

```
/jsp/ao/ApplicationStartUp.jsp
```

but it has been called without passing through an Action.

Either pass through an Action, or remove Struts tags from JSP called directly.

For a welcome file, I'd go with the latter.