# org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /index.jsp at line 3

Tags: jsp, struts2, taglib

i am building simple aplication  in struts with tablib and creating somple form i am facing exception i chekced many times and tried every thing but unable to resolve issue.

i know there are so many anserof this question but still not able to find  or resolve my problem

**Index.jsp**

```
<%@ taglib   prefix="S" uri="/struts-tags" %>  

<S:form action="register">  
<S:textfield name="name" label="Name"></S:textfield>  
<S:textfield name="lname" label="LName"></S:textfield>  

<S:submit value="register"></S:submit>  

</S:form>
```

**FOLLOWING JAR FILE USING**

```
common-lang3.jar
commons-fileupload-1.3.jar
commons-io-2.0.1.jar
commons-logging-1.1.3.jar
commons-logging-api-1.1.jar
freemarker-2.3.19.jar
javassist-3.11.0.GA.jar
ognl-3.0.6.jar
struts2-core-2.3.15.3.jar
xwork-core-2.3.15.3.jar
```

Exception

type Exception report

message An exception occurred processing JSP page /index.jsp at line 3

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

```
exception 



  org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /index.jsp at line 3

    1: <%@ taglib   prefix="S" uri="/struts-tags" %>  
    2:   
    3: <S:form action="register">  
    4: <S:textfield name="name" label="Name"></S:textfield>  
    5: <S:textfield name="lname" label="LName"></S:textfield>  
    6:     


 Stacktrace:
        org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:575)
        org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:477)
        org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:395)
        org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:339)
        javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
        org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)


    root cause 

    The Struts dispatcher cannot be found.  This is usually caused by using Struts tags without the associated filter. Struts tags are only usable when the request has passed through its servlet filter, which initializes the Struts dispatcher needed for this tag. - [unknown location]
        org.apache.struts2.views.jsp.TagUtils.getStack(TagUtils.java:60)
        org.apache.struts2.views.jsp.StrutsBodyTagSupport.getStack(StrutsBodyTagSupport.java:44)
        org.apache.struts2.views.jsp.ComponentTagSupport.doStartTag(ComponentTagSupport.java:48)
        org.apache.jsp.index_jsp._jspx_meth_S_005fform_005f0(index_jsp.java:105)
        org.apache.jsp.index_jsp._jspService(index_jsp.java:74)
        org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
        javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
        org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:439)
        org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:395)
        org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:339)
        javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
        org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)


    note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/7.0.64 logs.
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["The Struts dispatcher cannot be found" error while deploying application on WebLogic 12.1.3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31336754/the-struts-dispatcher-cannot-be-found-error-while-deploying-application-on-web)

Comment: Hello Roman C  please provide me ur persnol detail to communicate on  struts 2i am new here thanks